# Call method from whiten the class in WCF service C#.Net 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have WCF service code like this:

```
public class Service : IService
{
   public string method1()
   { 
      return string;
   }

   public list<x> getproject()
   {
      string str = method1();
   }
}
```

When i'm trying to call `method1` from `getproject()` its saying:

> Method1 does not exist in current context

- What I'm doing wrong? Please suggest.

Comment: Have you declared `method1` in your interface?

Answer (score 2):

1)  `public string method1() { return string;}`  < - - this syntax is incorrect.

2)  `public List<x> getproject()` suppose to be written : `public List<some valid type> getproject()`...

when i fixed that i didn't had this error message...

Comment: Its just an example i have given, not the whole code. Syntax are correct. Can you please tell me how you fixed that?